# How to Solve SQL Integrity Constraint Violation Exception

Tags: java, sql, persistence.xml

I created an entity class that has the same properties as project.java, and created a class where I can persist the entity object. Also, I created a database using databases in Netbeans using embedded `JDBC`. I have the `persistence.xml`, which provides the properties to connect the db, and is used the persitence class on `entitymanagerfactory` object. The connection seems fine but I am having `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'PROJECT_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.` error.

Is it ok to create the db manually (executing the ddl) or should I create the table in the `persistence.xml` using `property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"" value="create-tables` ?

Regards

Comment: The exception tells you clearly you can't have the value as NULL.Either you should put checks in your code and make sure you insert non-NULL values [proper values of PROJECT_ID] or remove the constraint on the database based on your application requirement

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of the column `PROJECT_ID`.

You can either do this in your code, for example by using the annotations `@SequenceGenerator` or `@GenericGenerator`,
or use db features (trigger) to set the id during insert.